# NFS not allowing hosts specified in config to mount share

Tags: domain-name-system, nfs, mount, internal-dns, nfs4

I am having an issue where NFS is refusing to allow hosts that are specified in the config file to mount the share.

I am running an NFS server on Debian 10, BTRFS filesystem.

my `/etc/exports` reads:

```
/share  192.220.189.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) *.domain.lan(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

I am trying to mount from `host.domain.lan`, but when I try to mount the share I get the following:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting server.domain.lan:/share
```

The server log reads:

```
rpc.mountd[PID]: refused mount request from <host.domain.lan's ip> for /share (/share): unmatched host
```

I have verified that the server can resolve host.domain.lan's hostname courtesy of a local DNS server.

The mounting DOES work if I explicitly specify `host.domain.lan` in `/etc/exports` as opposed to `*.domain.lan`. This will not do however as I want to serve the folder to an entire subdomain of FQDNs.

I can find nothing about this online, and I have exhausted every option I can think of, please help!

Comment: Is that your only export?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, I have another export set up exactly like the one in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the domain name is not resolving correctly in DNS.

What do you get if you use the `host` command on the server to try to resolve the client's ip address to a hostname?   DNS may not have the correct reverse mapping set up for this to work.

Comment: It returns `Host not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. Which is weird, because if I explicitly specify host.domain.lan, it mounts just fine.

Comment: It's not weird... it's not even unusual.  The name is registered for forward resolution but not reverse resolution.   It has to be registered for both directions for this to work.

Comment: Works perfectly after setting up reverse DNS resolution. Thank you! For anyone reading this in the future, when setting up your PTR records, remember to use `host.domain.lan.`, not `host.domain.lan`. Would have saved me hours knowing this.